# Best practices for consuming WebAPI backend from MVC WebApp

Tags: c#, authentication, cookies, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api2

I'm creating a WebAPI based SaaS application. This WebAPI can be used alone without the need for a user interface, requires a basic authentication sent with every request made to the WebAPI and returns some objects when the methods are called and authenticated.

Now I'm facing a big problem: I'm creating a WebApp in MVC (but it could be any language) and I can't figure out how to call my WebAPI endpoint without the need to keep username and password in order to authenticate the WebAPI request every time I call a method.

What are the best practices in this particular case?
I can't seem to find any suitable solutions...

So far I have tried to create a custom cookie with the help of a custom implementation of the `HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add` method, where I store in the `userData` of the Cookie the pair of username and password encrypted. In this way I can call the WebAPI methods specifying each time the `BasicAuthenticationCredentials` with the correct username and password, but this seems to me a very unmaintainable way to do the job in the long run.

I also wanted to try the OAuth2 way, but I can't find a well written guide on how to implement an authentication server based on a custom user table from SQL Server (and the first five pages of the Google result list didn't help me, they did actually make me even more confused about this topic, the whole OWIN and Katana thing...).

I can provide further information in case someone is willing to help me out.

Thanks in advance,
Stefano.

Comment: This link may help you to find good sources: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/aspnet-identity-recommended-resources

Comment: thanks @RuardvanElburg , will definitely check this out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a good tutorial about how to implement your own OAuth2 server:

http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

The main idea behind using OAuth is that you'll only need a username and password for your first request, and after that, you'll get an access token that will be used to get access to the API. This access token will have a lifetime, and once it has expired, the user will need to request a new access token (either by sending the user credentials again, or by using a refresh token that will be used as a credentials substitute).

The nice part behind this approach is that since the access tokens have a lifetime, even if one of those tokens gets compromised, you can just revoke it (or wait until it expires, for example, you can create tokens that will be renewed every 5 minutes or even less. It's up to you), the client will automatically ask for a new one, and that will be the end of the story. On the other hand, if you were always receiving the user credentials and those credentials got compromised, the user will need to change them and the risk will be there until the user finally changes his credentials (and here's a manual process where the user needs to be aware about this problem, while the OAuth approach is just refreshing those tokens all the time).

Also, remember to keep all the communication over HTTPS, since the tokens are sensitive information, and you don't want an eavesdropper getting the access token or even worse, the refresh token by just intercepting the communication. If he's able to do something like this, then even tokens refreshing every minute will be a useless approach against someone getting every token that you send.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm actually trying to learn as much as possible from that link you provided. Just another question: would it be a good practice to store the token received from the server in the `userData` of the cookie? And what would a call be like from my MVC front-end after I have authenticated through the OAuth server of the WebAPI? Should I pass the token in the request everytime? Thanks again.

Comment: Well, it depends. It seems like you're planning on creating a web application where you'll be the only one using the API, and it'll not be an API available for any person wanting to use it (i.e. Ebay's API). If that's the case, then I think that it'll be a lot better to store that token in the database as an encrypted value. After all, remember that the token is now the same as a temporal username and password, so it needs to be threated as sensitive information. About the request, yes, you'll need to send the access token on every request, so the server will be able to identify you.

Comment: Uhm, maybe I explained myself in a bad way... I meant to ask if it is a good practice to store the received token in the front-end... Imagine this scenario: your front-end app asks the WebAPI for a token, WebAPI sends a token for you to authenticate in the next requests. When you want to make a request from your front-end you will have to add to the headers of the request the token previously sent to you. This token could be saved in the client's device for further authentication until it expires... but what's the best practice for doing so? Sorry for the wall of text :D

Comment: But as far as I understand, you're talking from the consumer's perspective, and you can't do anything there. They can go as safe as storing that token as an encrypted value, or as bad as just saving it in a post-it. It's up to them. As an API consumer, what I do is to store my tokens as an encrypted value in a DB, because I want my app. consuming the API to be the only one knowing the token.

Comment: Now, If you're talking about a user implicitly sending the request for a token, you create that token and you store it in its cookie, such that your app will always get the token without the user not even knowing about that. Then maybe OAuth2 is not what you need, OAuth is useful to provide access to your API to third parties, but if you're the one consuming your API all the time, then you can go with the default authentication mechanism, where your user gets authenticated, you store a session cookie and you verify if it's a valid session cookie on every request ([Authorize] attribute in MVC).

Comment: Ok that's the best way for me (the last one you wrote). Thank you again for helping me, you saved me. If I knew how to mark this post as the answer, I would do it, but I think I don't have enough reputation yet...

Comment: Yeah, I think that you should see a green check below my answer's score. And don't worry if you don't have enough reputation yet, at least I could help you to get this clear :)